# How to show that gcd(|a|,|b|) = gcd(a,b)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to show that gcd(|a|,|b|) = gcd(a,b) ? 
I tried many ways but not convinced that im doing it right. i tried to look at different scenarios where :

a,b>0

a,b<0

a>0,b<0

but I know I am doing it totally wrong.

Comment: Hinr. $a$ and $|a|$ have exactly the same divisors.

Comment: Same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2937369/how-to-show-that-gcda-b-gcda-b) in the linked dupe, i.e. since $\,d\mid |x|\iff d\mid x\,$ we infer that $|a|,|b|$ and $\,a,b\,$ have the same set of common divisors so they have the same *greatest* common divisor.

Answer (score 1):

Show that every common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is also a common divisor of $|a|$ and $|b|$.  Then vice verse.  Since the set of common divisors of $a$ and $b$ is the same as the set of common divisors of $|a|$ and $|b|$, the largest element in each set has to be the same.

Another way is to invoke Bezout.  If $d=\gcd(a,b)$ then there exist integers $x$ and $y$ so that $d=ax+by$.  By adjusting the signs on $x$ and $y$ you can get a similar expression for $\gcd(|a|,|b|).$